# Reinstalling php5-mysql extension on ubuntu server without deleting mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Im extremely sorry because this isnt a strictly progamming problem, but i've exhausted my chances, and figured someone here is bound to be able to help.
So,I installed `libssh2` extension on my ubuntu server, which (im guessing) changed the extension dir of my php because i ketp getting this warning:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Unknown command in /path/to/my/file.php

the file has no syntax problems, as it was working before i installed libssh2.

After that, I removed said extension, but it still doesnt work. I reinstalled php5 from scratch and now `php -m` shows that mysql is not installed, however when I do `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` it says that its installed.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

(I should note that I dont want to unninstall mysql or phpmyadmin for I have important information on my DB)

Thank you

Comment: At first, try to install php5-mysqlnd, this is a new driver. Than check /etc/php5/conf.d/ to mysql config will be present.

Comment: Checkout php.ini file - make sure, that this extension is enabled. Also, mysql is deprecated, cosider switching to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: locate `mysql.so` on your system (probably somewhere in `/usr/lib/php5/....`).

When you find it, make sure it matches the `extension_dir` PHP is using (`php -i|grep extension_dir`.  If it isn't in that path, copy it there.